# How to make remote git repository even with another git repository?

Tags: git

I have a local checkout of a remote git repository from github, e.g. `origin/master`, and I have a fork of this repository at e.g. `fork/master`.

Is there a simple command or chain of commands to make the local checkout and the forked repository even with the `origin` branch?

At the moment I do not know better than use the following commands

```
git reset --hard origin/master
git push --force fork master
git fetch --all
git pull
```

in some random order until the local checkout and the remote repository `fork` are even. Maybe there is a more simpler way to ensure the 'evenness' of the checkouts?

Comment: Do you want to synchronize a single branch (the `master` branch in your example) or all branches ?

Comment: a single branch

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way would be :

```
# from your local master branch :
git pull --ff-only origin master
git push fork master
```

If `pull --ff-only` does not work, this would indicate that someone force updated the master branch on origin, so you would fall back to :

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
git push --force fork master
```

---

My initial answer, which became too convoluted to my taste :

- to update your local view of `origin` :

  ```
  git fetch origin
  ```

`git fetch --all` is the same as specifying all remotes after git fetch (in your case, it should be `git fetch origiin fork`), so it also does  the job.

- to update your local ref :

  ```
  # a. you seem to know that you can throw away your local changes,
  #    reset --hard would work for you :
  git reset --hard origin/master

  # b. the usual command to update your ref would be git pull :
  git pull origin master

  # c. if you have already fetched origin, you can use origin/master
  #    to merge or rebase your local branch :
  git merge origin/master
  # or
  git rebase origin/master
  ```
- to set the remote `fork/master` exactly to `origin/master` :
  you can use any reference that points to the correct commit.
  Here are three ways to get the same result :

  ```
  #  a. you can use origin/master directly :
  git push fork origin/master:master

  #  b. you can update your local master branch,
  #     then push your local 'master' ref to the 'fork' remote :
  git reset --hard origin/master
  git push fork master

  #  c. if you have the correct sha1, you can use that too :
  git push fork <sha1>:master
  ```